# How to force LinqToXML to write XAtribute value as "&" instead of "&amp"?

Tags: linq-to-xml

In the following 2 lines of code (which are independent from each other), I need the resulting XAttribute value to come out as "&PlusSomeMoreCharacters" instead of what the framework is doing "&ampPlusSomeMoreCharacters". I know why the framework does it, it's just following the correct xml standard. However the system that will read my resulting xml file doesn't care about the XML standard, it just uses an XML like syntax but it'll break if it finds the string "&amp" instead of "&", so please don't lecture me about the xml standard.
I need to force LinqToXml to generate a file where the "&" is not replaced with "&amp".
I know I can just grab the resulting file and modify it via Regex but that'd look kinda messy in my code, I'll only use that as a last resource.
I have already tried using the Unicode instead of the "&", that wouldn't work...

Code below:

`snSettingNode.SetAttributeValue("MyValue", "&PlusSomeMoreCharacters");`

`myXmlNode.Add(new XElement("SomeName", new XAttribute("Value", &PlusSomeMoreCharacters)));`

Comment: Just replace `&amp;` with `&` after serialization....this is the most simple way...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately .Net is really not written to make this easy. One approach is to create a wrapper for `XmlWriter` that allows you to write raw attribute values.

```
public class XmlRawAttribWriter : XmlWriter, IDisposable {
    XmlWriter baseWriter;
    bool disposedValue;
    HashSet<string> RawAttributeNames;
    bool LastAttributeIsRaw = false;

    public XmlRawAttribWriter(XmlWriter b) => baseWriter = b;
    public XmlRawAttribWriter(TextWriter output, XmlWriterSettings settings, string[] rawAttributeNames) {
        RawAttributeNames = rawAttributeNames.ToHashSet();
        baseWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings);
    }

    public static XmlRawAttribWriter Create(TextWriter output, XmlWriterSettings settings, params string[] rawAttributeNames) => new XmlRawAttribWriter(output, settings, rawAttributeNames);

    public override WriteState WriteState => baseWriter.WriteState;
    public override void Flush() => baseWriter.Flush();
    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns) => baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns);
    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count) => baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    public override void WriteCData(string text) => baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch) => baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count) => baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    public override void WriteComment(string text) => baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset) => baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    public override void WriteEndAttribute() {
        LastAttributeIsRaw = false;
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }
    public override void WriteEndDocument() => baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    public override void WriteEndElement() => baseWriter.WriteEndElement();
    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name) => baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    public override void WriteFullEndElement() => baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text) => baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count) => baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    public override void WriteRaw(string data) => baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns) {
        LastAttributeIsRaw = RawAttributeNames.Contains(localName);
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }
    public override void WriteStartDocument() => baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone) => baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns) => baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    public override void WriteString(string text) {
        if (LastAttributeIsRaw)
            baseWriter.WriteRaw(text);
        else
            baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }
    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar) => baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws) => baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!disposedValue) {
            if (disposing) {
                baseWriter.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `XmlRawAttribWriter` in place of `XmlWriter` - here are some sample uses:

```
public static class LinqXmlExt {
    public static string GetRawAttribXmlString(this XNode x, params string[] rawAttributeNames) {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {
            var ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            ws.Indent = true;
            if (x is XText)
                ws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            var sw2 = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var ws2 = new XmlWriterSettings();
            using (var w = XmlRawAttribWriter.Create(sw, ws, rawAttributeNames)) {
                x.WriteTo(w);
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string ToRawAttribString(this XNode x, params string[] rawAttributeNames) => x.GetRawAttribXmlString(rawAttributeNames);
}
```

With this, you can take get an XML string for an `XDocument` that has a raw attribute value:

```
var xmlString = xml.ToRawAttribString("MyValue");
```

If you needed to, you could modify the `XmlRawAttribWriter` to track the current element by storing the `localName` in the `WriteStartElement` method to only affect attributes on certain elements, passing in something like "element:attribute" to match against.

If you use other methods (such as `XDocument.Save`) you could create corresponding extension methods (e.g. `SaveRaw`) that take attribute names to have their values output as raw.